# Jqgrid issue, the datetimepicker addon for Jquery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, datetimepicker

I'm trying to use this [addon](http://trentrichardson.com/2010/04/19/timepicker-addon-for-jquery-ui-datepicker/) which is just what I need, but unfortunately does not work, I've been stuck on this a few days and I can not fix it, someone could help ..?

Here is the [home page](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) of the addon timepicker

... and here is my javascript code ...

```
colModel: [
           { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 50 },
           { name: 'Entrada', index: 'Enlaces', width: 80, sortable: true, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { dataUrl: '/Entrada/Listado/'} },
           { name: 'FechaInicio', index: 'FechaInicio', width: 90, editable: true, edittype: "text", editoptions: {
                            dataInit: function (el) {
                                $(el).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                                    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                                        var $input = inst.input;
                                        var $row = $input.parents("tr");
                                        $("#list").jqGrid('saveRow', $row.attr("id"), false);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        },
           { name: 'HoraInicio', index: 'HoraInicio', width: 80, sortable: true, editable: true, edittype: "text", editoptions: {
                            dataInit: function (tm) {
                                $(tm).datetimepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
                            }
                        }
                        }
                  ]
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

regards

Comment: if you can see I'm using UI datepicker ,and it's work fine ;)

Comment: Hm... could you explain what is going wrong?  Also if we could see the site or a demo or at least have some html code along with the js, that'd be great.

Comment: The problem is that the DateTimePicker control does not appear, my question is if I am doing well the function (or function call), I implements this addon like the datepicker, and I think this would work, but doesn't. On the other hand because the control jqGrid I'm using only works making calls from JavaScript code, no code associated HTML that I can provide and the js I'm using is the same that can be downloaded from the home page. Thanks for your commet Joseph. Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(el).datetimepicker( {
                           changeMonth: true,
                           changeYear: true,
                           showSecond:true,
                           dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
                           timeFormat:'hh:mm:ss',
                           hourGrid: 4,
                           minuteGrid: 10,
                           secondGrid: 10,
                           addSliderAccess: true,
                           sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false }
     });
```

Comment: You should add some explanation about how that solves the problem and why!